# Regex - Retreiving all Uppercase Chars from string, into one group

Tags: regex

I would like to retrieve all `[A-Z]` chars in a string. In `one` capture group.

```
XLarge
XLarge Short
XXL Short
```

The above should return

```
XL
XLS
XXLS
```

I've tried `[A-Z]+` but it fails when there is a space.

I need something that allows the capture to continue regardless of whats inbetween the uppercase chars.

Would this be achieved with the use of a negative lookahead? Thanks.

Comment: What about removing non-uppercase letters: Replace `[^A-Z]` with nothing.

Comment: You can't capture discontinuous content in a single group.

Comment: thanks Sebastian, handy to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't capture discontinuous strings together in regex, but you can remove everything you don't need (everything except uppercase letters) to simulate this.

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/xDYs1H/1)

```
[^A-Z\n]+
```

Results in:

```
XL
XLS
XXLS
```